# I have issues fetching user data from Firebase and showing it in a TextView/EditText

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

Fragment's Oncreate

```
public class HomeScreen_Profile extends Fragment {
    EditText Name, Email, Status, Quote;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);


        Name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        Email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Email);
        Status = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Status);
        Quote = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Quote);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        loadUserInformation();
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

LoadUserInfo Method

```
public void loadUserInformation() {

    final String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(uid);
    DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("ref").child(uid);
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                SetUpProfileHelper obj = postSnapshot.getValue(SetUpProfileHelper.class);

                String UserName = obj.getName();
                String UserEmail = obj.getEmail();

                Name.setText(UserName);
                Email.setText(UserEmail);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Loading UserDetails", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

For checking the working I have used only getName and getEmail in the method. I have no problem saving the userinfo, but fetching it is giving me a hard time because all the tutorials on the internet is fetching it and showing it in a ListView which I don't want. Can someone point out the error in this code?

Comment: what exactly is wrong?

Comment: the data isn't showing in the Edittexts

Comment: add a log and see if you are fetching anything or/and show your database

Comment: Log.d("TAG", obj.getName());
added this line of code... how do i check if i'm fetching data. sorry im still a beginner

Comment: in your logcat in android studio (bottom of the screen) debug the app and when you arrive to this activity check what `TAG` is equal to in the logcat

Comment: Alright let me check
https://ibb.co/kohtmb - my database

Comment: there is no child `ref` in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the location is wrong, you have this in the database:

```
  rootnode
        Users
           uid
            name:Userx
            email:userx@gmail.com
            phonenumber: number_here
```

and you want to get the `name` and `email`

do this then:

```
public void loadUserInformation() {

final String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String name=postSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString(); 
            String email=postSnapsoht.child("Email").getValue().toString()

        }
    }

   @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Loading UserDetails", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

Since the `uid` is under the `Users` node ( so direct `child`) and since you  want to retrieve the `uid` then just do a for loop to be able to get the data you need.

Comment: Omg... Dude thank you so very much... finally this thing working... sorry for wasting so many hours...